# Redirecting the AWS Route 53 Zone Apex to AWS S3 using an EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a naked domain I plan on using with QR codes (hence wanting to keep it as short as possible - e.g. qrc.me

I want to redirect this domain name to an AWS S3 Bucket (eventually a Cloudfront distribution), but AWS Route 53 won't let me add a CNAME record as the apex zone.

I know there is a service called http://arecord.net which looks like it does what I need (gives me an IP address which will map to the CNAME), but I have a full pool of fully customizable EC2 Instances at my disposal so I'd like to do something myself.

My question is then, how best to go about building an EC2 Instance that will run really lean, receive a request and simply redirect to the equivalent URL on the S3 bucket.

I'm a Windows guy, so am better in IIS, but if Apache does the same job with better performance I'm happy to go that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, since this post shows up fairly highly on search results, let me add an update:

Support for This has since been implemented in Amazon S3 so you can now host the zone apex in S3 as well - see http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/12/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

**Here's what worked for me:**

Given this record in Route 53:

```
www.foobles.com CNAME foobles.herokuapp.com
```

I would like to type in "foobles.com" and be redirected to "www.foobles.com"

1. **I created an EC2 micro instance with Ubuntu 12.04 and linked it to an elastic IP, let's
   say `11.55.21.22`.  Then I set an A record for `foobles.com`**

   `foobles.com A 11.55.21.22`
2. **I set up a basic Apache server:**

   *(from my local machine)*

   ```
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/cert.pem ubuntu@foobles.com
   ```

   *(from here on down, all commands are on the foobles server)*

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
3. **I created a rewrite rule**

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/foobles_zone_apex
   ```

   and put the following rule in it:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
   ```
4. **I enabled the apache2 rewrite module**

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
5. **and enabled the site**

   ```
   sudo a2ensite foobles_zone_apex
   ```
6. **finally, removed the default host**

   ```
   sudo a2dissite default
   ```
7. **and voila**

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

If all goes well, you should be able to do this:

```
curl localhost/blargh
```

and see this:

```
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.localhost//blargh">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

It seems pretty fast, even on a micro instance.  I won't be publicizing this URL very much, though, so in your case you would have to do a performance test or move it to a bigger instance.